# Data lost on vue dynamic component when back to parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-dynamic-components

I'm using Vue-form-wizard to create multi-step form. in one of the steps, I'm loading a dynamic component, and pass the data using v-bind and props to dynamic component. the data updates prefectly when we are on the dynamic component, but when I go to the next step all the changes lost on and rests to the parent component defaults! I tried  but that doesn't do anything. here is the example of what happens:
the html:

```
<div id="app">
<div>
  <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
    <tab-content v-for="tab in tabs"
                v-if="!tab.hide"
                :key="tab.title"
                :title="tab.title"
                :icon="tab.icon">
      <component :is="tab.component" v-bind={'form':form}></component>
    </tab-content>
  </form-wizard>
 </div>
</div>
```

and the js will be:

```
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
Vue.component('step1', {
 template:` <div> My first tab content <br>
             </div>`,
 props:['form'],
 created(){
            this.form = 'that other form'; 
      alert(this.form);
 }
 }
)
Vue.component('step2', {
 template:`<div>  My second tab content </div>`
})
Vue.component('step3', {
 template:`<div>  My third tab content </div>`
})
Vue.component('step4', {
template:`<div> Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple </div>`
})
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
    return {
  form:'this form',
    tabs: [{title: 'Personal details', icon: 'ti-user', component: 'step1'}, 
    {title: 'Is Logged In?', icon: 'ti-settings', component: 'step2', hide: false}, 
    {title: 'Additional Info', icon: 'ti-location-pin', component: 'step3'},
    {title: 'Last step', icon: 'ti-check', component: 'step4'},
    ],
  }
 },
 methods: {
  onComplete: function(){
      alert(this.form);
   }
  }
})
```

please help me.
thanks alot

Comment: You can use `keep-alive` in dynamic components. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components

Comment: i've tried it and didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
 props:['form'],
 created(){
      this.form = 'that other form'; 
      alert(this.form);
 }
```

you are changing a prop. [Don't do that](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and
> the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to
> the child, but not the other way around. This prevents child
> components from accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can
> make your app’s data flow harder to understand.

Instead, the child should emit an event that the parent acts on to update the data item. I like to create a computed in the child to wrap up that behavior so I can treat it like a variable that I can assign to.

In the snippet below, I use the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) to make the update clean. I also call [`$nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) after setting the value to give the event time to be handled.

```js
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
Vue.component('step1', {
  template: ` <div> My first tab content <br>
             </div>`,
  props: ['form'],
  computed: {
    proxyForm: {
      get() {
        return this.form;
      },
      set(v) {
        this.$emit('update:form', v);
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.proxyForm = 'that other form';
    this.$nextTick(() =>
      alert(this.proxyForm));
  }
})
Vue.component('step2', {
  template: `<div>  My second tab content </div>`
})
Vue.component('step3', {
  template: `<div>  My third tab content </div>`
})
Vue.component('step4', {
  template: `<div> Yuhuuu! This seems pretty damn simple </div>`
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      form: 'this form',
      tabs: [{
          title: 'Personal details',
          icon: 'ti-user',
          component: 'step1'
        },
        {
          title: 'Is Logged In?',
          icon: 'ti-settings',
          component: 'step2',
          hide: false
        },
        {
          title: 'Additional Info',
          icon: 'ti-location-pin',
          component: 'step3'
        },
        {
          title: 'Last step',
          icon: 'ti-check',
          component: 'step4'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onComplete: function() {
      alert(this.form);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-form-wizard@0.8.4/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-form-wizard@0.8.4/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <form-wizard @on-complete="onComplete">
      <tab-content v-for="tab in tabs" v-if="!tab.hide" :key="tab.title" :title="tab.title" :icon="tab.icon">
        <component :is="tab.component" :form.sync="form"></component>
      </tab-content>
    </form-wizard>
  </div>
</div>
```